# php function: the html did not display

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I created a `function` called `portfolio` but unfortunately the `html` of the `code` are not display while the function from `wordpress` is working.

```
function portfolio($id){
        $output = "<ul class=\"recentWorks port\">";
            if (have_posts()) : {
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            query_posts("&cat={echo $id;}&showposts=6&paged=$paged&order=ASC");
            }
            while(have_posts()) : the_post();

            $output .= "<li>";
                $output.= "<span>";
                the_title();
                $output .= "</span>";
          $output .= "</li>";
          endwhile;
         endif;
          $output .= "</ul>";
          return $output;
      }
```

only the `the_title()` display while the `html` `wrap` the `the_title()` is all gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing your HTML in the `$output` variable, and returning the variable at the end of the function, try printing out your HTML as you need it. For example

```
print "<span>";
the_title();
print "</span>";
```

The reason is because `the_title();` is being printed immediately, but your HTML isn't, it is simply going into a variable, and returned by the function. The calling function would then be responsible for printing the variable, by which time it will printed after `the_title();`

Comment: so this is the reason when I use `echo` it work but don't work in `variable` thank you for the brief explanation I learn some new. but I prepare to use `echo` cheers.

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
while(have_posts()) : the_post();

            $output .= "<li>";
                $output.= "<span>";
                $output .= the_title(); // edited this line
                $output .= "</span>";
          $output .= "</li>";
          endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function portfolio($id) {
    $output = "<ul class=\"recentWorks port\">";
    if (have_posts()) {
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        query_posts("&cat={echo $id;}&showposts=6&paged=$paged&order=ASC");

        while (have_posts()) {
            $the_post = the_post();
            $output .= "
            <li>
                <span>
                    $the_post
                </span>
            </li>";
        }
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";
    return $output;
}
```

[Codex - The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Answer (score -1):

Use this code

```
function portfolio($id){
            $output = '<ul class=\"recentWorks port\">';
                if (have_posts()) : {
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                query_posts("&cat={$id}&showposts=6&paged=$paged&order=ASC");
                }
                while(have_posts()) : the_post();

                $output .= '<li>';
                    $output.= '<span>';
                    the_title();
                    $output .= '</span>';
              $output .= '</li>';
              endwhile;
             endif;
              $output .= '</ul>';
              return $output;
          }
```

Comment: It would be better if you explained 1) what the differences are between your source and the OP's, and 2) why you expect these changes to solve the OP's problem. If anything, this makes the problems worse, because you now output bad HTML.